# Django, serialize relations, object instead id

Tags: python, django, orm, django-models

I have problem around serialization and relations. I want get object instead object id. (Django 1.4)

This code is inside my view:

```
serializers.serialize("json", Projects.objects.all(), indent=5, use_natural_keys=True)
```

After serialize Project i got:

```
 [
      {
           "pk": 1, 
           "model": "work.projects", 
           "fields": {
                "count": 3, 
                "date": "2013-02-03T09:43:20.474Z", 
                "client": 1, 
                "status": false, 
                "service": 1
           }
      }
 ]
```

This is my model:

```
    from django.db import models

    class ServicesManager(models.Manager):
        def get_by_natural_key(self, name, price, unit):
            return self.get(name=name, price=price, unit=unit)

    class Services(models.Model):
        objects = ServicesManager()

        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        price = models.IntegerField()
        unit = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class CustomersManager(models.Manager):
        def get_by_natural_key(self, name, city, street, post_code, phone, nip):
            return self.get(name=name, city=city, street=street, post_code=post_code, phone=phone, nip=nip)

    class Customers(models.Model):
        objects = CustomersManager()

        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        post_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        nip = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Projects(models.Model):
        client = models.ForeignKey(Customers)
        service = models.ForeignKey(Services)
        count = models.IntegerField()
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        status = models.BooleanField(null=False)

        def natural_key(self):
            return (self.count, self.date, self.status,) + self.service.natural_key() + self.client.natural_key()
        natural_key.dependencies = ['work.services', 'work.customers']
```

**This is solution (Model):**

```
from django.db import models

class Services(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.name,self.price,self.unit)

class Customers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    nip = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.name,self.city,self.street,self.post_code,self.phone,self.nip)

class Projects(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Customers)
    service = models.ForeignKey(Services)
    count = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(null=False)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.count, self.date, self.status, self.service.natural_key(), self.client.natural_key())
```

**And view code (for UTF-8)**

```
serializers.serialize("json", Projects.objects.all().filter(pk=1), indent=3, use_natural_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [DjangoFullSerializers](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers) from `wadofstuff`. Check out the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/wadofstuff/wiki/DjangoFullSerializers#Relations) on Relations. This should do the job.

Comment: I think it is possible without third part libraries. I read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/serialization/ but i'm doing something wrong because it dont work

Comment: You're calling self.service.natural_key() and self.client.natural_key(), but they don't seem to be defined in the models, only get_by_natural_keys() is.